# Can't change vm.dirty_ratio with /etc/sysctl.conf

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I recently bought an 120GB SSD drive and I wanted to tweak my OS for it.
I found some [tutorial](http://www.namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html) to do that and I followed it, but I've found some problems.

I wanted to change `vm.dirty_ratio` value to 60, so I've added this line: `vm.dirty_ratio = 60` at the end of my `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Then I rebooted my computer to apply changes.

Now when I use `sysctl vm.dirty_ratio` it returns 10, but I think with `vm.dirty_background_ratio` it worked.

What should I do to set it, or maybe I'm attempting to read it wrong way?
Thanks for help!

--EDIT--
/etc/sysctl.conf:

```
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
#

#kernel.domainname = example.com

# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
#kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3

##############################################################3
# Functions previously found in netbase
#

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable Spoof protection (reverse-path filter)
# Turn on Source Address Verification in all interfaces to
# prevent some spoofing attacks
#net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
#net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable TCP/IP SYN cookies
# See http://lwn.net/Articles/277146/
# Note: This may impact IPv6 TCP sessions too
#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
#  based on Router Advertisements for this host
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1


###################################################################
# Additional settings - these settings can improve the network
# security of the host and prevent against some network attacks
# including spoofing attacks and man in the middle attacks through
# redirection. Some network environments, however, require that these
# settings are disabled so review and enable them as needed.
#
# Do not accept ICMP redirects (prevent MITM attacks)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
# _or_
# Accept ICMP redirects only for gateways listed in our default
# gateway list (enabled by default)
# net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
#
# Do not send ICMP redirects (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
#
# Do not accept IP source route packets (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#
# Log Martian Packets
#net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
#

#My SSD tweaks
vm.swappiness = 5
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5 
vm.dirty_ratio = 60
```

Output of `sudo free --human`, because I'm unable to post it in comment:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3,8G       3,4G       473M       102M        65M       935M
-/+ buffers/cache:       2,4G       1,4G
Swap:         3,9G       280K       3,9G
```

Comment: @Fabby Unfortunately it didn't work. I'm getting same values as before. Also, for example `vm.swappiness` was working with spaces. I think spaces are allowed, but not when you want to do that from terminal.

Comment: (grasping at straws now) Add an additional [enter] at the end???  Delete the line and type it again???  (some invisible character crept in?)
It *should* just work...

Comment: @Fabby Well... It's still the same. I've added new line at the end of the file, rewrited line and rebooted PC. Is that line really important line for my disk, or can I just ignore it, because it won't short life of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per last comment: the `vm.dirty_ratio` just buffers pages to be written in larger chunks and is therefore not critical to your SSD life-cycle (mine has the standard 10). the `noatime` and `discard` options in fstab (the latter only if your disk supports trim) are more useful to keep the number of writes lower.

I also implemented `data=writeback` in `fstab` for my SSD disk, but only do that if you're running on a PC with a UPS (or have a laptop with a working battery)

Also: always make a back-up copy of `fstab` before changing anything!

Comment: I've already added those options to my fstab, except `data=writeback`, because my PC doesn't have UPS. Anyway, thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 2):

- Setting such a high vm.dirty_ratio might not be a very good idea. See: http://lwn.net/Articles/572911/
- Your updated settings should be added to a file in /etc/sysctl.d (e.g. something like `/etc/sysctl.d/60-local-dirty-bytes.conf`), as sysctl.conf is curretly not read on startup. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/1388068
- `pm-utils` reset the vm.dirty_bytes settings. You need to disable the `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode` script that resets these variables, for example by putting an `exit 0` on the second line of this script. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1407818

Comment: I think I was exaggerating a little bit. Lifetime of SSD is not as short as I thought, so I'll leave everything as it is for now. Anyway, thanks for answer and some knowledge. :) If my mind changes I'll come back to your answer. Also, how much does `vm.dirty_ratio` change disk I/O operations?

Comment: These settings do change how long it takes for data to be written to the disks. I don't think they will have a huge impact on the volume of data written to the disks.